# What are the advantages/disadvantages of using !important vs high specificity to override the style an element?

Tags: css

During the construction of an Angular directive to wrap a bootstrap select, I ran into a problem where bootstrap has a default style for an element and I need to override it. Therefore I have 3 options:

- Change the default
- Use !important
- Increase the specificity of the style

I do not want to change the default because it is still valuable elsewhere.

Here is the html:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The troublesome bootstrap css is:

```
ul.dropdown-menu {
  ...
  padding: 5px 0;
  ...
}
```

My goal is to increase the padding on the left hand side to 50px (I am building a tree). So my options are:

```
custom-directive li {
  padding-left: 50px !important;
}
```

Or simply increase the specificity like so:

```
.dropdown-menu custom-directive li {
  padding-left: 50px;
}
```

The generally accepted advice is to avoid `!important` but what are the advantages and disadvantages of using `!important` vs high specificity. The code has been greatly simplified to work as a question.

Comment: When you use !important, it basically locks the parameter and it can't be changed dynamically - only by hardcoding. I would recommend always to specify the path if you can so that it overwrites default & can be overwritten by !important in the future if needed.

Comment: This is a pretty open ended question, but here's how I look at it: If you use `!important`, that will also affect other tags and elements that you may not want to target and then would have to rely on specificity anyway to revert other elements you did not intend to affect. I would error on the side of specificity over `!important` if you have the option.

Comment: Yeah, this is intentionally a broad question. But the answer should be specific. There are several specific questions on SO you always get the same answer. I am hoping for depth here.

Comment: You forgot about the worst thing you could do to a fellow developer. You can combine a high specific selector and add `!important` to it. The advantage of the `!important` flag is, that it is the only selector that can actually override declarations made in `style` attributes and other `!important` declarations. You should use `!important` wisely and as little as possible. Your selectors should be a specific as required but not more. Working like this makes it possible to extend your code later on.

Comment: @NicoO I like your point that `!important` is the only thing that can override declarations in `style` attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Read through [this chart](https://specifishity.com/specifishity.pdf) on CSS specificity. Estelle (the author) likens `!important` to the atomic bomb approach. It's heavy-handed and should only be used as a last resort.

You want to do your best to keep your CSS towards the upper-left corner of the chart, i.e. your second example is better.

Best practice is to keep the number of selectors <= 3.

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: Thanks for the note, I just updated the link.

Answer (score 1):

`important` is overriden by another `important` so eventually one can get full of `important` declarations and clutter the css styles, if many overrides are needed

on the other hand, specificity is overriden by another specificity (equal or more specific), usualy easier to override if needed, less clutter

using specificity is recommended, but using `important` has its merits (for example when specificity cannot be used, or when an otherwise non very specific declaration must retain some styles from being overriden)